# Django Field.Unique = False (giving an integrity error)

Tags: python, django-models

I am creating models for a registration page.
I tried to set unique = False on a CharField, because i don't need unique value on my database (e.g. firstname, passwords, lastname)

Unfortunately I am getting an integration error, and when I set unique = True, my page works, but it wont accepts duplicate value.

Is there any ways I can make my database accepts duplicate values

```
from django.db import models
class Accounts(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    birthdate = models.DateField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Comment: `CharField` accepts duplicates per standard (`unique=False`) so there's no need to even use the `unique` tag on those fields, unless you would want it to be `True`. Have you tried storing duplicate values without the `unique` tag present on those fields? Can you please provide with any fill error messages you get in those cases?

Comment: Hi @Johan. i already tried it sir without the unique tag but still i get an error. IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: reg_app_accounts.last_name.

Comment: @ArgelPolicarpio then it's because those unique constraints are already in your database schema. Altering the model is not enough, you must create and apply a migration too.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` after setting `unique=False`. 
However, you shouldn't need to explicitly set `unique=False` on a `CharField` in the first place since it already defaults to `False`.

Comment: You may need to delete all entries with duplicate `username ` and `email` for the migration to run successfully

Comment: @Tobey That should only be needed when you try to apply a unique field. In this case the author tries to remove a previous unique condition.